# Return new ActionResult with value without using ControllerBase

Tags: c#, .net-core, actionresult

I need to return an `ActionResult` containing an object, however, I do not inherit from `ControllerBase`, so I'm unable to use the `Ok`, `BadRequest` etc. methods. How can I do this?

---

More info:

The reason I do not inherit from `ControllerBase` is that I hold a generic Response object, which contains a method that returns an `ActionResult`. The logic to determine *which* ActionResult should be returned will be in this method.

---

I've tried:

- `ContentResult`

  This gives me the option to provide a value, but only accepts a string `Content` value.
- `StatusCodeResult`

  This doesnt give me the option to provide an object to use as the value.
- `OkResult`, `BadRequest` etc.

  This doesnt give me the option to specify a value.

---

My Code:

```
public enum ResponseStatus 
{
    Ok, 
    BadRequest,
    // ...
}

public class ResponseObject<T>
{
    public ResponseStatus Status { get; set; }
    public T Value { get; set; }

    public ActionResult ToActionResult()
    {
        switch (Status)
        {
            case ResponseStatus.Ok:
               return new SomethingThatIsOk(this); // this doesnt exist, I dont know to return, hence the question

            case ResponseStatus.BadRequest:
               return new SomethingThatIsBadRequest(this); // this doesnt exist, I dont know to return, hence the question

            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple derived results that can be used to get the desired behavior.

```
public class ResponseObject<T> {
    public ResponseStatus Status { get; set; }
    public T Value { get; set; }

    public ActionResult ToActionResult() {
        switch (Status) {
            case ResponseStatus.Ok:
               return new OkObjectResult(this);

            case ResponseStatus.BadRequest:
               return new BadRequestObjectResult(this);

            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Use the one appropriate to your desired status.

[ObjectResult Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.objectresult?view=aspnetcore-2.2) has a few derived classes that worked for this scenario,

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.AcceptedAtActionResult
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.AcceptedAtRouteResult
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.AcceptedResult
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.BadRequestObjectResult
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ConflictObjectResult
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.CreatedAtActionResult
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.CreatedAtRouteResult
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.CreatedResult
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NotFoundObjectResult
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.OkObjectResult
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.UnauthorizedObjectResult
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.UnprocessableEntityObjectResult
System.Web.Http.BadRequestErrorMessageResult
System.Web.Http.ExceptionResult
System.Web.Http.InvalidModelStateResult
System.Web.Http.NegotiatedContentResult<T>
System.Web.Http.ResponseMessageResult
```

but I would suggest you review the API documentation for any other classes that may suit your needs.

All the `ControllerBase` does is wrap the creation of the result in a method

```
/// <summary>
/// Creates an <see cref="OkObjectResult"/> object that produces an <see cref="StatusCodes.Status200OK"/> response.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="value">The content value to format in the entity body.</param>
/// <returns>The created <see cref="OkObjectResult"/> for the response.</returns>
[NonAction]
public virtual OkObjectResult Ok([ActionResultObjectValue] object value)
    => new OkObjectResult(value);
```

[Source](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ControllerBase.cs#L301)

```
/// <summary>
/// Creates an <see cref="BadRequestObjectResult"/> that produces a <see cref="StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest"/> response.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="error">An error object to be returned to the client.</param>
/// <returns>The created <see cref="BadRequestObjectResult"/> for the response.</returns>
[NonAction]
public virtual BadRequestObjectResult BadRequest([ActionResultObjectValue] object error)
    => new BadRequestObjectResult(error);
```

[Source](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ControllerBase.cs#L1746)